# Dynamically assign elements to object

Tags: r, dataframe, get, paste, assign

In R, I am trying to dynamically select columns of a data.frame called DF.  If

```
 cutOffYear=2014
```

and

```
forecast_years=3
```

Then this piece of code

```
paste0("DF$X",cutOffYear+1:forecast_years)
```

yields:

```
[1] "DF$X2015" "DF$X2016" "DF$X2017"
```

Assuming all three columns exist in DF how do I assign the column variables to the characters?

I have tried a lot of combinations of get, assign and paste0 but I am failing.

Comment: Do not use `$`, use `[[` or `[`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `[` to select the columns.  It is often error prone when using `$`.  If we need to get the output as a `data.frame` with columns specified in the `paste`d combination of 'cutOffYear', 'forecast_years', then the below code should work fine

```
DF[paste0("X", cutOffYear+1:forecast_years)]
```

Comment: @joel.wilson  I am not sure what the intention here is, Is it just to select the columns or do some operations?  If it is data.table, only a single column can be selected with `[[` (as it is the behavior of `[[`, otherwise, you have to add `with = FALSE` for subsetting

Comment: agreed ! @akrun

Comment: Thank you @akrun. This solves it and it is so much more efficient and neat.